# SCD Type 2 - Handling Intraday changes?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have a merge statement that builds my SCD type 2 table each night. This table must house all historical changes made in the source system and create a new row with the date from/date to columns populated along with the "islatest" flag. I have come across an issue today that I am not really sure how to handle.

There looks to have been multiple changes to the source table within a 24 hour period.

```
    ID      Code         PAN     EnterDate   Cost     Created
  16155 1012401593331   ENRD    2015-11-05  7706.3  2021-08-17 14:34
  16155 1012401593331   ENRD    2015-11-05  8584.4  2021-08-17 16:33
```

I use a basic merge statement to identify my changes however what would be the best approach to ensure all changes get picked up correctly? The above is giving me an error as it's trying to insert/update multiple rows with the same value

```
DECLARE @DateNow DATETIME = Getdate()
IF Object_id('tempdb..#meteridinsert') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #meteridinsert;

CREATE TABLE #meteridinsert
             (
                          meterid INT,
                          change  VARCHAR(10)
             );
             
             
             MERGE
INTO         [DIM].[Meters] AS target
using        stg_meters     AS source
ON target.[ID] = source.[ID]
AND          target.latest=1
WHEN matched THEN
UPDATE
SET              target.islatest = 0,
                 target.todate = @Datenow
WHEN NOT matched BY target THEN
INSERT
       (
              id,
              code,
              pan,
              enterdate,
              cost,
              created,
              [FromDate] ,
              [ToDate] ,
              [IsLatest]
       )
       VALUES
       (
              source.id,
              source.code ,
              source.pan ,
              source.enterdate ,
              source.cost ,
              source.created ,
              @Datenow ,
              NULL ,
              1
       )
       output source.id,
       $action
INTO   #meteridinsert;INSERT INTO [DIM].[Meters]
            (
                        [id] ,
                        [code] ,
                        [pan] ,
                        [enterdate] ,
                        [cost] ,
                        [created] ,
                        [FromDate] ,
                        [ToDate] ,
                        [IsLatest]
            )
SELECT     ([id] ,[code] ,[pan] ,[enterdate] ,[cost] ,[created] , @DateNow  ,NULL ,1 FROM stg_meters a
INNER JOIN #meteridinsert cid
ON         a.id = cid.meterid
AND        cid.change = 'UPDATE'
```

Comment: Why do you use `@datenow`, if you said that there are many records for the same natural key to load? Don't you need to update the `todate` with the `startdate` of the next record for that natural key?

Comment: I was actually following this guide but I get what you're saying (especially in this case) it would make more sense to use the startdate of the next record

https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2012/01/using-t-sql-merge-to-load-data-warehouse-dimensions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can do it using `merge` statement, but I would prefer to use typicall `update` and `insert` approach in order to make it easier to understand (also I am not sure that `merge` allows you to use the same source record for update and insert...)

First of all I create the table `dimscd2` to represent your dimension table

```
create table dimscd2 
(naturalkey int, descr varchar(100), startdate datetime, enddate datetime)
```

And then I insert some records...

```
insert into dimscd2 values
(1,'A','2019-01-12 00:00:00.000', '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000'),
(1,'B','2020-01-01 00:00:00.000', NULL)
```

As you can see, the "current" is the one with `descr='B'` because it has an `enddate` NULL (I do recommend you to use *surrogate keys* for each record... This is just an incremental key for each record of your dimension, and the fact table must be linked with this surrogate key in order to reflect the status of the fact in the moment when happened).

Then, I have created some dummy data to represent the source data with the changes for the same natural key

```
-- new data (src_data)
select 1 as naturalkey,'C' as descr, cast('2020-01-02 00:00:00.000' as datetime) as dt into src_data
union all
select 1 as naturalkey,'D' as descr, cast('2020-01-03 00:00:00.000' as datetime) as dt
```

After that, I have created a temp table (`##tmp`) with this query to set the `enddate` for each record:

```
-- tmp table
select naturalkey, descr, dt, 
  lead(dt,1,0) over (partition by naturalkey order by dt) enddate,
  row_number() over (partition by naturalkey order by dt) rn
into ##tmp  
from src_data
```

[image: lead_row_number]

The `LEAD` function takes the next start date for the same natural key, ordered by date (`dt`).
The `ROW_NUMBER` marks with `1` the oldest record in the source data for the natural key in the dimension.

Then, I proceed to close the "current" record using `update`

```
update d
set enddate = t.dt
from dimscd2 d
  join ##tmp t
    on d.naturalkey = t.naturalkey
   and d.enddate is null
   and t.rn = 1
```

And finally I add the new source data to the dimension with `insert`

```
insert into dimscd2
select naturalkey, descr, dt, 
  case enddate when '1900-00-00' then null else enddate end 
from ##tmp
```

Final result is obtained with the query:

```
select * from dimscd2
```

[image: output]

You can test on this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=270ef4d7a830699b2e6beebe8d208186)

Comment: This is a really good approach and I hadnt even considered using update/insert (mainly because when I've researched implementing SCD 2 it's either using SSIS or MERGE)

Thank you for this, it has worked and taught me a new approach!

Comment: `MERGE` statement fits well for SCD1 dimensions... not sure if you can use this feature for SCD2 dimensions, because you use the oldest record to update (the `enddate` for the previous "current") and also to insert it, and normally merge allows you to do with each record one operation, not two